# Server-side logout of current session

Tags: javascript, meteor

This ends all active sessions of a user:

```
Meteor.users.update(userId, {$set: {'services.resume.loginTokens': []}})
```

How can I end only the current session?

Comment: did you already try deleting only the latest loginToken?

Comment: @tomsp No, and i doubt that would be reliable if multiple users were using the same account at the same time.

Comment: hmm, right. maybe i misunderstood what you meant by current session.

Comment: I meant the opposite of `Meteor.logoutOtherClients();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var userId = this.userId
var conId = Accounts._getLoginToken(this.connection.id)

Meteor.users.update(userId, {$pull: {'services.resume.loginTokens': {'hashedToken': conId}})
```